# isInterrupted() is not triggered

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

Experimenting with the interrupt(), found that the isInterrupted() is always false.

Another thing is that replacing the **isInterrupted()** with **Thread.interrupted()** will make the thread stop.

Could someone explain why this behavior occurs?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread counter = new Thread(new Worker());
        counter.start();
        counter.interrupt();
    }

    static class Worker extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            String msg = "It was interrupted"; 

            while (true) {
                if (isInterrupted()) {
                    System.out.println(msg);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two thread objects: `Worker` is a thread on its own, and you wrap it in a new separate `Thread` object:

```
Thread counter = new Thread(new Worker());
```

The two thread objects have two interrupt flags.
Calling `counter.interrupt()` sets the interrupt flag in the outer thread object, while calling `isInterrupted()` checks the interrupt flag in the inner "Worker" thread object.

The reason why `Thread.interrupted()` makes the thread stop is because it checks the interrupt flag of the *currently running thread* which in this case will be the outer object.

It would be clearer code if you got rid of the outer thread object and wrote:

```
Worker counter = new Worker();
counter.start();
counter.interrupt();
```

Answer (score 3):

You should initialize your counter like that:

```
 Thread counter = new Worker();
```

Since `Worker extends Thread` but it is passed as `Runnable`, you have two different instances of `Thread`.

However `Thread.interrupted()` will interrupt the current thread, thus it works.

As an alternative to the above solution, replace `isInterrupted()` with `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()`.